# How to set schedule to tweet status from website to Twitter?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I'm planning to create website that allow user to tweet status from my site to their Twitter timeline. Since now, I can let them tweeted to their Twitter timeline successfully; but I want them to set schedule for their tweet to Twitter. It means that their status will be post on Twitter timeline according to their scheduled.

**Here are other websites did:**

1. [www.laterbro.com](http://laterbro.com)
2. [www.futuretweets.com](http://futuretweets.com)

**Here is code that can tweet to Twitter timeline**

```
<?php

session_start();
$message = "I want to set datetime to tweet new status";
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$parameters = array('status' => $message);
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

simple way:

use a cron job to run your php script from the command line

it can run every minute and look for tweets to make based on the schedule

more complex/scalable:

use a message queue to do something similar

EDIT: Example cron job:

cron jobs are used to run scheduled tasks on Unix/Linux/OSX, you add/delete/edit them using this command:

```
crontab -e
```

Once the editor is opened you can put in a simple cron job like this:

```
* * * * * echo `date` >> /tmp/foo.log
```

This would just append the date to the file /tmp/foo.log every minute. You can set this going then check the /tmp/foo.log file to see the results:

```
cat /tmp/foo.log
```

You could create a cron job which just ran your PHP file from the command line every minute.

Note: There are 5 *'s (asterisks) in the above example, this says how often the job will be run. See the Wiki page to see how you can customize this to run at whatever period you want:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: i don't how how to write cron job and execute it. Can you give me an example about that?